# Search of element from List in the String

Tags: string, list, erlang

I have a list like `List = ["google","facebook","instagram"]` and a string `P1 = "https://www.google.co.in/webhp?pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr"`.

Now I need to find which element of `List` is present inside the `P1`.

For this I implemented below recursive function, but it returns `ok` as final value, is there a way that when (in this case) `google` is found, then `H` is returned and terminate the other recursive calls in stack.

I want this function to return `google`.

```
traverse_list([],P1)-> ok;
traverse_list([H|T],P1) ->
 Pos=string:str(P1,H),
 if Pos > 1 ->
   io:fwrite("Bool inside no match is ~p~n",[Pos]),
   io:fwrite("inside bool nomathc, ~p~n",[H]),
   H;
 true->
   io:fwrite("value found :: ~p~n",[Pos])
 end,
traverse_list(T,P1).
```

Comment: One issue is that the output functions of the io module return ok if they are successful. You might try your code again using the io_lib library and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `ok` because the stop condition of your recursion loop does it:

```
traverse_list([],P1)-> ok;
```

For this you should use `lists:filter/2` or a list comprehension:

```
List = ["google","facebook","instagram"],
P1 = "https://www.google.co.in/webhp?pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr",
lists:filter(fun(X) -> string:str(P1,X) > 1 end,List), 
% or
[X || X <- List, string:str(P1,X) > 1],
```